# Can you cancel a page from closing

Tags: silverlight, google-chrome

Is there any way to cancel a page from closing depending on some condition in my `Silverlight` app? The purpose: While working in this app there is a part I want to stay open until they end a certain task then the browser can react as normal. I just don't want any accidental closing to happen. If this is not possible that is fine and I will work around it. The app is hosted in an `ASPX` page.

After some work here is the wrapper(VB>NET);

```
Public Class SWC
 ''' <summary>Event arguments for handling the window close event.</summary>
  Public Class HtmlWindowCloseEventArgs : Inherits CancelEventArgs
   ''' <summary>Gets or sets the message to display to the user asking them if they want to continue the window close.</summary>
    Public Property DialogMessage() As String
      Get
        Return _dialogMessage
      End Get
      Set(value As String)
        _dialogMessage = value
      End Set
    End Property
    Private _dialogMessage As String
End Class
 ''' <summary>Monitors the closing of the HTML window.</summary>
 Public Class HtmlWindowCloseMonitor
#Region "Events"
    ''' <summary>Fires when immediately before the window closes.</summary>
    Public Shared Event WindowClosing As EventHandler(Of HtmlWindowCloseEventArgs)
    Private Shared Sub OnWindowClosing(sender As Object, e As HtmlWindowCloseEventArgs)
      RaiseEvent WindowClosing(sender, e)
    End Sub
#End Region
#Region "Head"
  Private Const ScriptableObjectName As String = "HtmlWindowCloseMonitor"
  Private Const DefaultDialogMessage As String = "Are you sure you want to close the application?"
  Private Shared ReadOnly instance As HtmlWindowCloseMonitor

    ''' <summary>Constructor.</summary>
    Shared Sub New()
      If instance Is Nothing Then
        instance = New HtmlWindowCloseMonitor()
      End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub New()
      ' Register the scriptable callback member.
      HtmlPage.RegisterScriptableObject(ScriptableObjectName, Me)

      ' Retrieve the name of the plugin.
      Dim pluginName = HtmlPage.Plugin.Id
      If pluginName Is Nothing Then
        Throw New Exception("Cannot register the 'onbeforeunload' event because the Silverlight <object> does not have an ID. Add an ID attribute to the Silverlight <object> host tag.")
      End If

      ' Wire up event.
      Dim eventFunction = String.Format("window.onbeforeunload = function () {{" & Environment.NewLine &
                                    "var slApp = document.getElementById('{0}');" & Environment.NewLine &
                                    "var result = slApp.Content.{1}.OnBeforeUnload();" & Environment.NewLine &
                                    "if(result != null && result.length > 0)" & Environment.NewLine &
                                    "return result;" & Environment.NewLine & "}}", pluginName, ScriptableObjectName)
      HtmlPage.Window.Eval(eventFunction)
    End Sub
#End Region
#Region "Methods"
   <ScriptableMember()> _
   Public Function OnBeforeUnload() As String
     ' Check with event-listeners to see if any of them want to cancel the window-close operation.
     Dim args = New HtmlWindowCloseEventArgs()
     OnWindowClosing(Me, args)
     If Not args.Cancel Then
      ' No one wanted to stop the window from closing.
      Return Nothing
     End If
     ' Present the 'Are you sure' dialog to the use (via the browser).
     Dim message = If(args.DialogMessage IsNot Nothing, args.DialogMessage, DefaultDialogMessage)
     Return message
   End Function
#End Region
End Class
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind on onBeforeUnload / BeforeUnload event to ask the user.

Comment: HtmlPage.Window.AttachEvent("beforeunload", HandleBeforeUnload); and declare public void HandleBeforeUnload(object sender, HtmlEventArgs args){ .... }

Comment: should the `beforeunload` event match an event in the `ASPX` default page? I don't see one with this name.

Comment: Please see: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/02d2d6b7-5a5e-4142-857b-0c8e0aa5695a/cancelling-onbeforeunload-in-chrome-from-managed-code?forum=silverlightnet

Comment: Just found that about 5 minutes ago, and I am looking thru it.

Comment: I can see my code run thru the e.cancel and my message is not empty and there is no dialog. My Plugin.Id is working. I wonder about the javascript. I'll post it in the question.

Comment: and slApp variable is initialized as ... ?

Comment: It should be getting the <object> which is the SL app.